# Posting entire model back to controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner in asp.net mvc and web technologies. 
Now I am stuck at some point. I have a create user page. When admin user wants to add a new user, he is redirected to create user page with an empty data class. In that page, the data class is filled up. Now I want to return that model's data back to the controller using a POST method.

What I am trying to achieve is to directly post the entire model as a JSON object back to the controller and it is always null.

**On create new user click :**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateUser()
{
    var newUser = new User();
    return View(newUser);
}
```

**My CreateUser View code :**

```
@model WebApplication7.Models.User
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CreateUser</title>
    <h2>Create new user</h2>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.userName, new { @class = "", id = "txtUsername", @maxlength = 6 })
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.passWord, new { @class = "", id = "txtUsername", @maxlength = 6 })
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>First Name : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.firstName, new { @class = "", id = "txtUsername", @maxlength = 6 })
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Last Name : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.lastName, new { @class = "", id = "txtUsername", @maxlength = 6 })
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Display name : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.displayName, new { @class = "", id = "txtUsername", @maxlength = 6 })
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Email : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.emailID, new { @class = "", id = "txtUsername", @maxlength = 6 })
                </td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="button" name="btnClear" value="Submit" class="btn-Clear" onclick="Submit()" />
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Submit function code :**

```
<script>
    function Submit() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/UserManagement/SubmitNewUserData",
            data: JSON.stringify({ userData: model }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: function () {
                return "error";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**My Controller Code :**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitNewUserData(User userData)
{
    if (userData != null)
    {

    }
    return Json(true);
}
```

The `userData` here is null always. Please help me to post back that model to this controller. Thank you.

Comment: You just need `data: JSON.stringify(user),`

Comment: @Satpal : oops..sorry. That was test code. I was trying to pass like `data: JSON.stringify({ userData: model }),`. Is that possible?

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and change it to `data: $('form').serialize(),` and wrap all your form controls inside a `<form>` element. You will also need to add `return false;` as the last line of code to prevent the default submit

Comment: Please share the User class from server side and the model object from client side

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Working great.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not indicated what the value of `model` is, but in order to work, it would need to

```
var model = {
    userName: $('#userName').val(),
    passWord: $('#passWord').val(),
    ... // etc for each property of User
};
```

assuming you remove all you `new { id = "txtUsername" }` attributes which is generating invalid (duplicate) name attributes.

A far easier solution is to wrap all you form controls in a `<form>` tag and then use `.serialize();` to correctly serialize all your form controls. The script would then be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SubmitNewUserData", "UserManagement")', // always use Url.Action() to generate your url's
    data: $('form').serialize;
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        ServiceSucceeded(msg);
    },
    error: function () {
        return "error";
    }
});
return false; // cancel the default submit
```

To improve this further, remove your `onclick="Submit()"` and handle the `.submit()` event using [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
       ....
    });
    return false;
});
```

The `if (!$(this).valid()) {` will allow you to handle client side validation, which you should be doing by including `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(..)` helpers and including the relevant `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts, and adding validation attributes to your model properties so that you get both client and server side validation.

Side note: A password field should be generate with `@Html.PasswordFor()`. Its also unclear why your using ajax rather than a standard submit (why would you want the user to stay on the same page and edit it again?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will definitely change my code to `Unobtrusive Javascript`. Thanks for the advice regarding `@Html.PasswordFor()` and same `id` for all controls. This is just test code. Thought of changing it after doing the functionality part. I am using ajax for submitting the code since this is partial view and not main view. I need to return data to the controller from this partial view. So this is the only way to post data back to the main view's controller from partial view right?

Comment: Not necessarily. The only reason to use ajax is if you want to stay on the same page. If that's what you want to do then its the correct choice (its just not clear from the code you have show why you want to stay on the same page)

Comment: But I would certainly start adding validation attributes to you properties so that you get client and server side validation

Comment: Yes I want to stay in the same page itself after closing the partial view. Did you mean validation in model like `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Name")]`. Or some sort of javascript validation?

Comment: Exactly, and `[StringLength]` etc. And is `emailID` is actually and email address, then a `[EmailAddress]` for that one. If the user leaves the field blank, the `if` check will cancel the submit and display the error message(s) - no point sending back invalid data

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable advice.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this, after you give the form a name:

```
 <script>
function Submit() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/UserManagement/SubmitNewUserData",
        data: $("#formname").serializeArray(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
            return "error";
        }
    });
}
```