# Losing complete Model when posting Ajax values to controller

Tags: c#, razor, model-binding, html.listboxfor

What i want to do is have 2 listboxes (left, right) where left would have all products entities except the ones that are present in my Contract Entity and in the right the products in my Contract Entity.

I am having this issue that when i pass 1 parameter (string) I can receive them correctly in my controller but whenever i pass my model with it as a second parameter i loose my model completely. This is what i have:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditContract(ContractViewModel model, string selectedProducts)
```

View (Javascript/JQuery):

```
  function GetSelectedProducts() {

        var listbox = document.getElementById("productsForContractListbox");
        var txt = "";
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < listbox.length; i++) {
            txt = txt + "\n" + listbox.options[i].text;
        }

        $('#SelectedProductForContracts').val(txt);
        var selectedProducts = $('#SelectedProductForContracts').val();

        var model = $('form').serialize;

        $.post('@Url.Action("EditContract", "Contract")', { "model": model, "selectedProducts": selectedProducts});
    }
```

Html helper listboxes:

```
// listbox for my contract products
@Html.ListBoxFor(c => c.Contract.Products, productsForContract, new { ID = "productsForContractListbox", @class = "form-control" })

// listbox where all products except the ones in my contract are loaded
@Html.ListBox("allProducts", allProducts, new { ID = "allProductsListbox", @class = "form-control" })
```

HiddenFor for the SelectedProductForContracts from my Model:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.SelectedProductForContracts, new { ID = "SelectedProductForContracts", name = "SelectedProductForContracts" })
```

Model:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public List<SelectListItem> SelectedProductForContracts { get; set; }
```

When having the post data containing only the selectedProducts, i get my values but lose my model, when i add my model i get my model but lose my selectedProducts values.

I tried several things like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486599/posting-entire-model-back-to-controller-using-ajax) but couldn't get them to work in my case (i am doing something wrong probably but don't know what ...)

Can anyone help me towards the proper way of achieving this cause i see many ways but i hope there must be an elegant way of binding everything to 1 model without having to use javascript/Jquery ?

Kind regards!

Comment: Have you tried adding  `selectedProducts` property to your `ContractViewModel` view model ?

Comment: @Shyju, thank you for replying. I have added a string property to my ContractViewModel and binded it to the ListboxFor c  => c.selectedProducts but this didn't work. I can do a Request.Form["hiddenForName"] and handle these values but i don't feel its the correct way?

Comment: a List<SelectListItem> is probably not able to be defined in a single hidden variable.

Comment: @RichardHubley, YES! you are right... This works. You can post it so i can mark it as an answer if you want to ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<SelectListItem>` is not able to be defined in a single hidden variable

Comment: This post has been flagged as low quality and is in danger of being deleted. Please consider editing the answer with a proper solution to the given question.

Comment: @BryceSiedschlaw that's fair. OP did say it helped them though.

Comment: This has surely helped me a lot and fixed my problem, i didn't know that it didn't support List<SelecListItem> Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2